# IE: Add FormData polyfill to angular with formly

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, polyfills, ngx-formly

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-polyfill and nxg formly in a angular project my form has a file upload field configured in formly. Now we have to support IE and a polyfill is required to get this working but I have no idea how to add it. The error is that FormData.get is not supported in IE and needs a polyfill.

polyfills.ts

```
...
import 'formdata-polyfill';
```

form.component.ts

```
...
this.fields = [
    {
      key: 'file',
      id: 'field_import_file',
      type: 'file-upload',
      templateOptions: {
        required: true,
        fieldName: 'Import File',
        floatLabel: 'always',
        appearance: 'outline'
      },
      validation: {
        validators: ['file-upload']
      }
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not seen any good solutions but I did make a workaround, posted below in case anyone else has this issue. Note this is a workaround not a proper solution.

in this case I made a hidden form on the page and created a fake file upload field in formly that simulated the event's of the hidden form upload field.

fake-upload.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/material';
import { CustomTemplateOptions } from '../../../../../../kup-core/src/lib/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fake-upload-field',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button
        (click)="onClick()"
        [id]="id"
        type="file"
        [formControl]="formControl"
        [formlyAttributes]="field"
        (change)="onChange()"
        ngDefaultControl
        [name]="id"
        mat-stroked-button
      >
        Choose File
      </button>
      <input
        type="text"
        [value]="to.data.filename"
        class="fake-file-upload-input"
        (change)="onChange()"
      />
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .fake-file-upload-input {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: none;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class FakeUploadComponent extends FieldType {
  to: CustomTemplateOptions;

  onClick() {
    document.getElementById('realFileUpload').click();
  }

  onChange() {}
}
```

then manually added the file values back into the formly form model,

then hidden the forms submit buttons created a fake form submission panel that simulated the events and validation of the formly form the old fashioned way.

```
  onHiddenFileUploadChange($event) {
    const el: any = document.querySelector('.fake-file-upload-input');

    this.stagedFile = $event.target.files;
    this.stagedFilename = $event.target.files[0].name;

    el.value = this.stagedFilename;
    this.checkForm();
  }

  triggerSave() {
    const form: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('importForm');
    const button: HTMLElement = form.querySelector('button[type=submit]');
    button.click();
  }

 private onImportTypeChanged(value: FormlyFieldConfig[]): void {
    this.viewModel.importTypes.map(type => {
      if (type.name === value[0].formControl.value) {
        value[1].formControl.patchValue(type.description);
        this.stagedType = type.name;
      } else if (!value[0].formControl.value) {
        this.stagedType = '';
      }
    });
  }
```

This was the only way I could find to workaround formly's lack of legacy ie support without forking formly and customizing it directly.

Answer (score 1):

`formdata-polyfill` should be imported `polyfills.ts` file in order to be loaded before the app.

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

...
import 'formdata-polyfill';
```

And to submit the file you'll need to construct a `Formdata` instance based on the submitted model once the form triggers a submit event.

```
export class AppComponent {
  ...

  onSubmit(model) {
   const formData: FormData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', model.file);
   formData.append('firstname', model.firstname);
   ...

   // send
   this.http.post(url, formData) ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for way to do this within formly, it's their file upload component thats using FormData.get but it's baked in, the issue isn't on submit so I'm currently going down a custom field that acts as a fake file upload field while the real one sits outside the form.

Comment: I see, have tried importing `formdata-polyfill` in the `polyfills.ts` file I think that's where it should be added.